# Increase the Length of the block title field

Tags: 6, blocks

How to increase the length of the block title of a block?. By default its length is set to 64 characters. Please Help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will be tricky. Block titles can only be 64 character. You need to alter the database and make the title field for blocks longer.

Put this in a custom modules .install file.

```
function mymodule_schema_alter(&$schema) {
  // Change length of title field for block.
  $schema['block']['fields']'title'] = array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 128,
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => '',
    'description' => 'Custom title for the block. (Empty string will use block default title, <none> will remove the title, text will cause block to use specified title.)',
    'translatable' => TRUE,
  );
}
```

and then alter the block title maxlength attribute in a form alter

`$form['block_settings']['title']['#maxlength'] = 128;`

Another way is that you put your long title in the content of the block instead of using the "real" block title field.

In Drupal 7 I would hint you to checkout Bean module, but as this is Drupal 6 I'm not sure.

Comment: Although correct, it would be much better to use [`hook_schema_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_schema_alter/6) rather than a direct query :)

Comment: I've updated the answer to use hook_schema_alter instead.

Comment: Now you get an upvote ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a cleaner way of accomplishing this:

in mymodule.module:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'block_admin_configure') {
    $form['settings']['title']['#maxlength'] = 128;
  }
}
```

in mymodule.install:

```
function mymodule_update_1() {
  $alt_spec = array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 128,
    'not null' => FALSE,
  );
  db_change_field('block', 'title', 'title', $alt_spec);
}
```

Credit goes to the commentors in this thread https://drupal.org/node/664834